# Fortune algorithm eigensolve

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalue

Does there exist an implementation of fortunes eigensolve algorithm?

At the moment i am trying to port it to python but it does not deliver correct results so far.
The only thing I found was the paper where he describes the algorithm [here](https://9p.io/who/sjf/eigensolve.html) and I don't understand where my algorithm goes wrong.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Poly, symbols
lamda = symbols('lamda')

#Creates generalized companion matrix
def gen_companion(p,S):
    #create lagrange coeffs
    L_i = []
    for i in range(len(S)):
        den_s = 1
        for j in range(len(S)):
            if (not (i == j)):
                den_s *= p(S[i]-S[j])
        p_s = p(S[i])/den_s
        L_i.append(p_s)
    #create lagrange matrix L 
    dim = S.shape[0]
    L = np.zeros((dim,dim),np.complex64)
    for i in range(dim):
        for j in range(dim):
            L[j,i] = np.abs(L_i[i])
    B = np.zeros((dim,dim),np.complex64)
    #Create Matrix S
    for i in range(dim):
        B[i,i] = S[i]
    return B-L
    


def eigensolve(p,n_iterations):
    A = np.polynomial.polynomial.polycompanion(coeffs).astype(np.complex64)
    S = qr_algorithm(A,n_iterations)
    for _ in range(n_iterations):
        L = gen_companion(p,S)
        S = qr_algorithm(L,n_iterations)
    return S[0]


def qr_algorithm(A,n_iterations):
    for _ in range(n_iterations):
        Q,R = np.linalg.qr(A)
        A = R @ Q
    return np.array([A[i,i] for i in range(A.shape[0])])

p = Poly((lamda - 10)*(lamda-20)*(lamda-4)*(lamda-5),lamda)
coeffs = np.array(list(reversed(p.all_coeffs())))


n_iterations = 10
v = eigensolve(p,n_iterations)
print("")
```

I only got the same eigenvalues I entered in the second part of the algorithm:

```
(20.153511+0j)
(20.153511+0j)
(20.153511+0j)
(20.153511+0j)
(20.153511+0j)
```

Comment: Could you describe the method somewhat more? There appear to be differences between the intended algorithm and the code. The algorithm appears to start with a polynomial and an approximate root set, like in Durand-Kerner, irregardless how bad the approximation is. The expected output seems to be an improved root set approximation.  The algorithm itself, I guess, is intended to compute the companion matrix for the operator `V to (XV(X) mod P(X))` in the basis of Lagrange polynomials. On this the primitive QR algorithm is applied (Francis QR already comes with shifting and deflation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula in the paper is

```
    l[i] = P(s[i]) / Q_S'(s[i])  =  P(s[i]) / prod( (s[i]-s[j]) for i!=j)
```

This can be implemented as

```
Q = np.poly(S)
dQ = np.polyder(Q)
l = np.polyval(P,S)/np.polyval(dQ,S)
```

Note that the vertical lines in the paper are wrong, or at least should not denote the absolute value.

As I noted in the comments, this variant of the QR algorithm is a pre-alpha version. Even the first variant by Francis recommended for implementation used shifts to accelerate the convergence of the smallest eigenvalues and thus the split of the matrix, deflated to the subspace orthogonal to the smallest eigenspace.

If one does not overly care about computation time, one can just use this primitive variant. It will converge to a normal form that allows to read off the eigenvalues. This normal form will have the eigenvalue in order of descending absolute values. Especially in the later stages of the root finder the companion matrix will already be close to diagonal. If the diagonal entries are not in the correct order, the QR algorithm will exchange them using small rotations, thus a large number of rotations. This overhead does not contribute to the precision of the roots/eigenvalues, and should thus be avoided. Which your implementation does automatically.

I'd like to direct your attention to the `np.diag` function and lists with constant elements. The companion matrix can then be constructed as

```
np.diag(S) - np.array(len(S)*[l])
```

Making these changes and returning always the full results gives as return value of `eigensolve` the expected

```
[20.      +0.j 10.000002+0.j  5.000003+0.j  4.000001+0.j]
```

Comment: Hello Lutz. Can you explain what you mean by QS in your second code block second line? Also I dont understand a 100% what you described in the first code block is that not exactly what I implemented?

Comment: I had first QS everywhere for Q_S, but in context it felt too long...

Comment: I'm not sure what is better, the product version or the derivative version in the denominator of the Weierstrass updates. With multi-point evaluation using FFT-like schemes, the derivative version is faster, but might be less precise. In any case, the product evaluation will have different errors than the derivative evaluation. With the sensitivity of polynomial roots to perturbations, this can have a noticeable influence.